# Mailboxer JSON Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, messaging

I am using the mailboxer gem and I wanted to go about making the conversation (show.html.haml) JSON format and also the mailbox (index.html.haml) JSON format.

I tried putting it a normal respond_to block like this

```
 respond_to do 
   format.json { render :json => @conversation }
 end
```

but it didn't work. It says the stack level is too deep. Is there something I'm missing?

These are the controller code

```
   def mailbox
     @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
   end

   def conversation
      @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])

   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out what the problem was, I needed to add a show and index into my conversations controller so that I could then render in json. For anyone else that may have this problem this was what I did and it worked fine.

```
   def index
     @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.json { render :json => @mailbox }
     end
   end    

   def show
     @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.json { render :json => @conversation }
     end
   end
```

Hope this helps!